# MacBook Pro won't load photos

Tags: photos

My MacBook Pro is not loading my photos anymore. I insert the SD card, as I have always done, iPhoto pops up and says loading photos, but then the error message pops up saying that the disc was not ejected properly when I haven't even touched it! Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Leslie,

Without further information, my first guess is a corrupted SD card. Try the following steps.
1) With the SD Card inserted, locate and launch Disk Utility.app
2) On the left column lists of hard disks, DVD/CD and other storage devices detected on your MacBook Pro.
3) Click once to select the SD card. This will cause the right half of the window to be populated with series of possible actions. The default action displayed is titled 'First Aid'. Locate the 'Verify Disk' button on the bottom right corner. Click once on it and allow some time for it to diagnose your SD card.
4) If the Disk Utility.app reports an error, click to grant it permission to fix it. Once it's done, quit Disk Utility.app
5) Relaunch iPhoto and see if it works.

If this helps, please mark your question as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I put the SD card in and iPhoto popped up and said loading photos, like it was reading the card. Then, that message popped up saying that it wasn't ejected properly and the icon disappeared from the desktop. I left the card in and went to disk utility, but the SD card was not listed on the left. Any other suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To rule out the card can you try it in a different device (ideally not the camera you've taken it out of).

To rule out a fault with the SD Card reader on the MBP can you test it with a USB card reader?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but what is a USB card reader?

Comment: @Leslie a card reader that you connect via USB rather than one build into the computer.

Comment: I don't have just a reader, but I tried leaving it in my camera and attaching the camera to my computer, but that wasn't working either...